# "Et si en plus d’être fatiguée, tu es/étais perdue ?": How does the change from "es" to "étais" affect the meaning of this specific conditional?

Tags: sens, temps-grammatical, conditions

> Et si en plus d’être fatiguée, tu **es** perdue ?

Here, I mean it as a near-rhetorical, "what (will you do) if ...?" question, but if I want to increase the level of hypotheticality by a few notches, is it acceptable to turn "es" into "étais", just as you do in a standard conditional subordinate clause?

> Et si en plus d’être fatiguée, tu **étais** perdue ?

I mean, does this phrasing retain the "what if ...?" meaning? The thing is that when I hear the "Et si ... Imparfait ..." construction, I can't help but associate it with a suggestion instead — such as:

> Et si tu **allais** faire un tour dans la ville ?

Answer (score 1):

-- Does this phrasing retain the "what if ...?" meaning?

It might keep the "what if..." meaning. The context will tell if it is a suggestion or not.

> Si tu es perdue, qu'est-ce que tu fais ?

makes:

> Si tu étais perdue, qu'est-ce que tu ferais ?

Suggesting someone to get lost would better be done by dropping the passive voice:

> Si tu te perdais, tu pourrais justifier ton retard !

Comment: Hi. Actually, I'm talking specifically about a dangling, incomplete sentence, as shown in my three examples. How do French speakers generally interpret the 2nd one? As a hypothetical conditional or a suggestion?

Comment: Still as a "what if" question. *Être perdu* is a state so is not the same as *se perdre* which is a process. You suggest a process more than a state. Same with *Si tu te faisais couper le cheveux* (process, might be either a "what if" or a suggestion) vs *Si tu avais les cheveux courts* (state, unexpected as a suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

*Si* introduit usuellement une proposition subordonnée. Exprimant une condition, son verbe est conjugué à l'imparfait de l'indicatif. Le verbe de la proposition principale se conjuguera au conditionnel.

Maintenant... quand il s'agit d'une interrogation, il n'y a pas de proposition principale.

Mais il n'y a aucune raison de changer la conjugaison du questionnement. => *Et si tu **étais** perdue ?*

*Si* se suffit pour exprimer une condition. C'est **si** qui l'exprime et non la conjugaison du verbe de la subordonnée. En ce sens l'usage d'un présent dans la subordonnée ne changera en rien la nature hypothétique de la subordonnée.

*Si tu **es** perdue* exprime donc tout aussi bien la condition. Ni plus ni moins.

La différence ? Elle se situera dans la réponse à la question.

Si le locuteur a utilisé le présent, son interlocuteur répondra... à l'indicatif, s'il a utilisé l'imparfait, l'interlocuteur répondra... au conditionnel.

On peut ainsi non pas augmenter le niveau d'hypothétique mais bien plutôt **adoucir** un ordre, un conseil... et plutôt que de dire :

*Si tu es perdue, prends une boussole!*, préférer *Si tu étais perdue, tu prendrais une boussole*.

Comment: Et si on a/avait/eût le subjonctif, en tant que *Si tu fusses perdue, tu prisses une boussole*?

Comment: @Carl Masens : Le subjonctif indiquant (à mon goût) bien assez l'hypothèse, **je** me passerais du *si* en l'occurrence. => *Fusses-tu perdue*. Mais en tous les cas, je ne vois pas la moindre logique de conséquence à *prendre* ensuite à l'imparfait du subjonctif.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that :

- Et si en plus d’être fatiguée, tu es perdue ? Comes with a general/theorical meaning. That could be in a discussion where someone says that she doesn't care about being tired and someone add "And what if you are tired **and** lost?". It's not truly happening.
- Et si en plus d’être fatiguée, tu étais perdue ? Comes with an actual/hypotetical meaning. It's for something that is happenning right now (tu es fatiguée) but with someting that is not (tu étais perdue). In this case it could be someone complaining wile walking that she is tired and someone explain that at least they are not lost ("yes you are tired but it could be worst. What if you were tired and lost?")

Answer (score -1):

You associate it with a suggestion because it actually is one. However, if I'm not mistaken, to keep the What.. if? you're looking for, I would add a comma after *Et si* to clearly divide the statements.

> Et si, en plus d'être fatiguée, étais perdue?

This, to me, sounds more like a question without removing any context from your sentence.